# How can I use timeline for double click in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

This is what I have done so far, it works just fine, but  when I double click, the double click event is fired and the single click event is fired, when I single click only the single click is fired of course.

```
long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {

  long currentClickedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long diffMillis = currentClickedMillis - currentMillis;
  currentMillis = currentClickedMillis;
  if (diffMillis > 500) {
    fireEvent(new FlightListEvents(FlightListEvents.FLIGHT_BUTTON_CLICKED, this.aircraft));
  } else {
    fireEvent(new FlightListEvents(FlightListEvents.FLIGHT_BUTTON_DOUBLE_CLICKED, this.aircraft));                   
  }
});
```

The other solutions on Stack Overflow do not work! They just count numbers of clicks and still have the same problem I have now.

Comment: beware: doing something completely different for double than for single click is  bad UX! Typically, the double should enhances/broaden the single.

Comment: @kleopatra but isn't counter intuitive for a double click to also fire single click events ?

Comment: @Elmehdi no, it's up the client app to differentiate :) Typical good UX f.i. is single - select, double start editing. Bad would be first start editing, second delete item .. so my first take on a problem like this would be to re-think the UX (vs. technically separate single/double - which is possible, as your answer correctly demonstrates :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem once and couldn't find the solution too, so I had to develop my own solution.
For that I used Javafx's `Timeline` which is gonna give you the ability to start a time line at your first click and depending on if you afterward make a second click or not, it is gonna consider it to be either a single click or a double click, but never both at the same time.
Here is my solution:

```
// initialize your timeline
final Timeline clickTimeline = new Timeline();
// minimum duration of a double click 500ms
Duration clickDuration = Duration.millis(500);
KeyFrame clickKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(clickDuration);
boolean isClickTimelinePlaying = false;
clickTimeline.getKeyFrames().add(clickKeyFrame);

addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
  if (isClickTimelinePlaying) {
    // when clicking the second time before the time line finishes
    isClickTimelinePlaying = false;
    fireEvent(new FlightListEvents(FlightListEvents.FLIGHT_BUTTON_DOUBLE_CLICKED, this.aircraft));
    clickTimeline.stop();
  } else {
    // when clicking for the first time
    isClickTimelinePlaying = true;
    // start the timeline
    clickTimeline.play();
  });
}

// if timeline finises without receiving a second click, consider it a single click
clickTimeline.setOnFinished(event -> {
  fireEvent(new FlightListEvents(FlightListEvents.FLIGHT_BUTTON_CLICKED, this.aircraft));
  isClickTimelinePlaying = false;
});
```